# Why does the motor only run between 170-180?

Tags: arduino

I'm using a brushless motor of 1000kv and an ESC simon30A. I power the motor using arduino adapter AC/DC 9v. When I try to run the motor using sweep example. The motor will only run when the value is between 170-180. How come other values below 170 won't run the motor? Is my ESC broken??

The model of bldc is A212/3T. 1000kv and ESC is Simon 30A . I'm using servo Library to control the speed.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to try to run the motors? Have you calibrated the ESCs? Have you armed them?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* rjadkin, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I posted back in April asking for more information about what you're trying to do, what you've done, what you're seeing, what code you're using, etc. I'm putting the question *on hold* to give you the opportunity to *edit your question* to provide the requested information. The question will be re-opened if you provide the requested edits, but if, as it appears, you abandon the post it will be automatically closed after a period of time.

Answer (score 1):

The sweep example is for servos. A brushless motor is not a servo. The sweep example attempts to turn the servo from 0 to 180 degrees and back to 0. So, the 0 - 180 value is not necessarily a PWM signal; it represents the rotation of a servo.

A DC motor won't turn without enough power being applied to overcome the static magnetic pull--you can feel if you try to turn the motor shaft. So, if you only apply small voltage (below whatever voltage 170 represents in your example), then the motor will just hum.

Comment: You are correct, for a PWM signal driving a motor directly, but I believe OP may be attempting the correct method of driving the motor because they are writing the PWM signal to an *electronic speed controller*. ESCs accept a control signal input and do the power electronics (switching) internally.